# about continuous and bijection funcion

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

For which sets $A$ and $B$, function $f: A \to B$ exists such that $f$ be continuous and bijection ?

1-$A=[0,1)$ and $B=(0,1)$

2-$A=[0,1]$ and $B=[0,1)$

3-$A=[0,1]$ and $B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}| x^2+y^2=1 \}$

4-$A=\mathbb{R^2}-(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q})$ and $B=(0,1) \cup \{2\}$

options 2 and 3 is not true because $A$ is compact so $f$ is homeomorphism and $A$ is not homeomorphic with $B$.

Answer (score 0):

None of he functions exist. I assume that the topology is inherited from the corresponding $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

For 1, 2, 3 there are no such functions. Say, for 1) consider the restriction $g=f|_{(0,1)}$. It is continuous bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)\setminus f(0)$. Since $(0,1)$ is connected, $(0,1)\setminus f(0)$ has to also be connected (continuous functions map connected spaces to connected spaces). But open interval minus a point is disconnected, a contradiction. Similarly for 2) $g$ is from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1)\setminus \{f(0),f(1)\}$, for 3) $g$ is from $(0,1)$ to a circle minus two points.

For 4, the domain does not have isolated points, while the codomain does. So if $f$ is such a function, then $f^{-1}(2)$ should be an open set in the domain, but $f^{-1}(2)$ is a singleton, which is not an open set in the domain.

Comment: continuous bijection from a compact space to Hausdorff space is homeomorphism.

Comment: In particular, this result comes from the fact that all maps from compact spaces to T2 spaces are closed: closed sets in compact spaces are compact, continuous images of compact are compact, and compact sets in T2 spaces are closed.

Comment: Also, saying $f^{-1}(2)$ is closed is insufficient: what's important is that it's not open as no point in the domain is isolated.

Comment: Thanks, I will modify the answer.

Comment: For 1) and 2) you can also argue that any continuous bijection between two real intervals is strictly monotonic, hence preserves the "type" of the interval (open, closed, or half-open-half-closed).

Comment: @AnneBauval.how we can show  any continuous bijection between two real intervals  preserves the "type" of the interval ?